# Custom post meta list only the upcoming events

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called "Events". One custom field is the date of the event and I need to query the posts based on this date, and only show future events. I've gotten close, but can't seem to figure out how to integrate the filter with the code I've already written. This is my code. thanks,

```
    $today = date('dd-MM-yy');
    $args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'events',
            'posts_per_page'    => 2,
            'meta_key'          => 'events_date', 
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'meta_value_num'    => $today,
            'meta_compare'      => '>'
        );

    $events = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I tried, It's not worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$today = date('dd-MM-yy');
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'events',
        'posts_per_page'    => 2,
        'meta_key'          => 'events_date', 
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
           array(
             'key' => 'events_date',
             'value' => $today,
             'compare' => '>',
           )
        )
    );

$events = new WP_Query( $args );
```